# Use GarageBand's metronome for practice

Tags: garageband

In GarageBand '09, I find that the Metronome plays only when I'm recording.

How do I use the Metronome just for practice?

Comment: So this question was 10 years ago. Is it still not possible to use the metronome in GarageBand without recording?

Comment: Same problem in Garageband 10.4.8 for macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could just start a recording every time you practice and delete it at the end. Not very practical probably.

Alternatively you could download [Metronome](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~ronfleckner/metronome/) which "is designed with the practicing musician in mind which means that it's fast and easy to use. Nearly all of Metronome's functions and settings can be changed by using a single key." Actually there are probably a lot of other metronome applications, this was just the first I found in Google.

Comment: So this question was 10 years ago. Is it still not possible to use the metronome  in GarageBand without recording?